Refresh token in middleware for Next.js 14 with next-auth
I'm running Next.js v14.2 and next-auth v4.24.
I am using middleware to intercept requests that go through my Next.js server and adding the Authorization header if they have a server session.
This is what the code looks like:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = await getToken({ req: request });
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  if (token?.access_token) {
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token.access_token}`);
  }

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}

However, I am encountering a problem where the user keeps the tab on idle for some time, then sends a request when the JWT has expired. Thus, the server receiving this forwarded request returns a 401.
I am aware getServerSession will automatically refresh the token, but when I tried implementing I got an error.
Here is the code:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  if (token?.access_token) {
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token.access_token}`);
  }

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}

Here's the error:
Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

How should I go about solving this?
